# search won't sit next to navigation

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a horizontal menu and want to place a search form in line with it but it appears left aligned on a new line.. I am new to html so just learning the basics (working on my third site just really got the hang of CSS).

```
<div id="nav">
    <span class="nav">
        <a href="#" alt="$"><span id="jqFade"><img src="images/skydevUpperNav.png"></span></a>
        <a href="#" alt="$"><span id="jqFade"><img src="images/goftbUpperNav.png"></span></a>
        <a href="#" alt="$"><span id="jqFade"><img src="images/genUpperNav.png"></span></a>
        <span id="searchBox">
            <form action="#" method="get">Search
                <input type="text" name="searchGoogle" size="12" maxlength="45" />
            </form>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post some code to show what you're trying that doesn't work?

Comment: you also need to post your css

Comment: You need to use `display: inline`. Example:<br>
[http://jsfiddle.net/HB9Z2/](http://jsfiddle.net/HB9Z2/)

Comment: Just a hint: I think you missed a `</span>`. Besides: `<span/>` is an inline element and it's not allowed to be parent of block elements like `<form/>`. Test your code with W3C validators.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;`

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wN6Ae/1/

CSS:

```
searchBox{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form elements are rendered as `block` by default, so you'll need to set the search box form to `display: inline-block;`. Wrapping block elements in spans is not an effective solution since it doesn't change the way the contained elements are rendered.

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf46a/

Comment: In fact it's not only ineffective (which could be overwritte with `display: block`), it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<ul>` with `<li>` tags for navigation and `float:left;` the list elements span is not nice. set `list-style-type: none;` if u dont whant the list styles displayed. `<img>` should be closed too -> `<img .... />`